# Сравнительный оборот или придаточное предложение?

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Некоторое время сквозь эту пелену еще доносился шум лиственниц, потом смолк и он, как будто задавленный густым снегом; ветер тоже стихал (Кор.).

Answer (score 4):

В придаточном предложении должна быть "своя" грамматическая основа (подлежащее и сказуемое). В данном предложении причастие ***задавленный*** относится к подлежащему ***он***, является его определением. Всё выражение ***как будто задавленный густым снегом*** — причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, а значит, отделяется от него запятой. ***Как будто*** здесь является союзом, само значение которого указывает на сравнение. Можно сказать, что сравнительный оборот выражен причастным оборотом.

[**КАК БУДТО (БЫ)**, *союз и частица*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_308)

> 1. **Союз**. То же, что «словно, будто». Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «как будто (бы)», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
> 2. **Частица**. В знач. «словно, будто, вроде» тесно связана со сказуемым. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Comment: Обещала посмотреть — извините, попозже.

Comment: Ну вот — попозже наступило. Конечно же не придаточное; конечно же союз. Поддерживаю и Вас, и Екатерину.

Answer (score 3):

**Предложением** конструкция *как будто задавленный густым снегом* **не является**. Это  **определение**.

Распространённое определение *как будто задавленный густым снегом* относится к **личному** **местоимению** *он* (*он* какой?), поэтому **обособляется**, где бы ни находилось в предложении.

Определение в форме **причастного оборота** имеет дополнительное **обстоятельственное значение** - ещё одно условие обособления.

*Как будто*  здесь **союз**, присоединяет конструкцию, которая **не входит в состав самостоятельного сказуемого *утих*** и не примыкает к нему тесно.

*Как будто* **может быть частицей**, ср.: *Шум был как будто задавлен (задавленный) густым снегом.* Здесь *был задавлен* - **сказуемое**, **запятую** между подлежащим и сказуемым **не ставим**.

Comment: Екатерина, спасибо! Благодаря Вашему ответу наконец-то осмыслил до конца первое своё решение: сначала интуитивно написал про союз, потом засомневался, исправил на частицу. Сейчас вернулся к союзу. :) Голосую за Ваш ответ.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Александр, я Вам тоже хочу сказать спасибо и за хорошие ответы, и за неизменный такт в общении с форумчанами. Это такая редкость - такт и осторожность в высказываниях! Ваш ответ я долго обдумывала, согласна с ним. Только функцию "как будто" действительно нужно было уточнить. Знаю, что Вы тоже сомневались.

Comment: Очень приятно получить такое спасибо!