# Когда сравнительные союзы БУДТО, СЛОВНО, КАК БУДТО переходят в частицы?

Tags: союзы, сравнительный-оборот

Действительно, с чего бы им туда переходить? Они что, меняют при этом свое значение?

Сравнительные союзы КАК, БУДТО, СЛОВНО, КАК БУДТО имеют определенную специализацию, но в большинстве случаев **взаимозаменяемы**.  Они могут относиться к словам, словосочетаниям, различным синтаксическим конструкциям, но при этом **сохраняют значение сравнения или уподобления**. Например: *Словно белою косынкой подвязалася сосна.  Ветер дул навстречу, как будто силясь остановить молодую преступницу.*

Вопрос задан по мотивам другого вопроса, где утверждалось, что союз КАК БУДТО является частицей в таком предложении: *Шум был как будто задавлен (задавленный) густым снегом*. [Сравнительный оборот или придаточное предложение?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460526/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

**А также информация из Справочника Грамоты.ру  вызывает у меня сомнения.**  Авторитетный, конечно, справочник, но у меня нет желания считать его источником  единственно верных суждений. **Тесная связь со сказуемым переводит союз в частицу?** Может и переводит, да не всегда.
Частица, как я считаю,  должна получить **другое значение взамен значения сравнения**. Рассмотрим, к примеру, два предложения.

(1) Ветер будто бы стих, но не надолго.  (2) Иногда ветер стихал, будто бы прислушивался к их шагам, но потом начинал дуть с прежней силой.

Здесь в обоих случаях союз тесно примыкает к сказуемому, но в одном случае это частица, а в другом союз. Или я ошибаюсь, как вы думаете?
Спасибо.

Примечание

Можно дать краткий ответ, как у Булгакова, **мне бы он понравился:**

– Если я не ослышался, вы изволили говорить…

– Нет, вы не ослышались, – учтиво ответил Берлиоз, – именно это я и говорил.

– **А вы соглашались** с вашим собеседником? – осведомился неизвестный, повернувшись вправо к Бездомному.

– **На все сто!** – подтвердил тот...

Comment: Sharon (рад, что Вы с нами), а что не так с Грамотой? Там ведь частица как раз и меняет значение — вместо значения сравнения имеем значение неуверенности, предположительности и т. п. Я именно так понимаю взятое в кавычки значение «словно, будто, вроде».

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо! В Грамоте, как мне кажется, все перемешано. Например: "Я как будто бы просветлел. Я увидел в человеке такие чудные качества, каких ранее и не подозревал".   Это сравнение (уподобление), а у них частица. Сравним: Ты как будто бы "просветлел" наконец? Имеется в виду, что-то понял. Это частица, имеет значение предположения. Вот это надо различать.